# Does "I've run for 3 months" sound correct?

Tags: present-perfect

What I'm trying to say is:

> I started running, as a habit, 3 months ago. And I haven't aborted it yet.

Can I just say "I've run for 3 months"? If so, then how should I say

> I run for 3 months nonstop

in present perfect tense? I know it doesn't make a lot of sense but let's assume I'm a superhero or whatsoever.

Comment: (1) "I've been running for three months now." or "I started running three months ago." Pragmatics demand that the obvious reading be assumed. (2) You can't be serious. "He was hiccoughing for three months nonstop."

Comment: "I have been a runner for three months now" removes ambiguity from the first statement.

Comment: @Edwin: I'm not sure what it is about certain verbs that makes the construction *I've run for weeks now* (or even worse, *I have drunk for hours*) so "awkward" compared to, say, *I've **smoked** for years*. The only thing that comes to mind is the business of IE speakers tending to say things like *I **have been knowing** this all my life*, but I'm not sure that's governed by the same "rules".

Comment: @FF Good spot. Probably the possible ambiguity with some verbs informs the situation. Verbs I'd suggest investigating include 'struggle', 'manage',  'argue' /  'knit', 'play' (of the piano say) / 'avoid' (with 'him'). I'd help, but we're off for an Italian.